# Expo/Metro/Minify: how to exclude specific variable names from getting mangled?

Tags: expo, minify, metro-bundler

I'm using Expo managed workflow.

Is there a way to exclude certain variable names from being mangled when Expo bundles and minifies my app in production mode?

I tried adding the following “reserved” array to the miniferConfig, but it had no effect:

path: node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js

```
...
minifierConfig: {
 mangle: {
  toplevel: false,
  reserved: [“myVariableName”] 
 },
...
```

Thanks